# NHibernate LINQ Where and Any throwing exception

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have the following code that is throwing a "Specified method is not supported" error:

```
var list = securityRepository.Query<IsAuthorized>().Where(
    ia => ia.SecurableObjectName == objectName
    && ia.PermittedActionName == permittedActionName
    && ia.ScopeName == scopeName).ToList();

var prins = repository.Query<Principal>().Where(
    p => list.Any(l => l.PrincipalId == p.Id)).ToList();
```

The second query with the `Any` is what is throwing.

I need to select a list of `Principal` whose id's are in the `list<IsAuthorized>`.

Comment: I'm not sure if ToList() does deferred execution or not. Try var list = ...ToArray()

Comment: ToList() executes the deferred execution of IQueryable... It does in EF at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, that the best what we can do with that type of query, is to move it to DB Server. Of course, only in case, that this is possible, that the first query is not returning results from external source. *Then we have to use a bit different technique.. but let's assume, that both tables are inside the DB.*

The second query, would be the OUTER Select, the first will be the INNER Select. To combine them, we will use the **IN** statement.

What we have to do is:

Firstly, let's adjust the first query, to return the One property/column, to be used later:

```
var list = securityRepository
    .Query<IsAuthorized>()
    .Where(
      ia => ia.SecurableObjectName == objectName
      && ia.PermittedActionName == permittedActionName
      && ia.ScopeName == scopeName)
    // .ToList();
    .Select(ia => ia.PrincipalId);
```

So, what we've done, is deferring the query execution *(no ToList() call)*. Instead, we created a SELECT clause with projection containing only one property/column.

Let's adjust what we have and need for the second query:

```
var prins = repository
    .Query<Principal>()
    //.Where(p => list.Any(l => l.PrincipalId == p.Id))
    .Where(p => list.Contains(p.Id)) // our subQuery
    .ToList();
```

And this, will produce something like this:

```
SELECT ... 
 FROM Pincipal p
 WHERE p.Id IN (SELECT ia.PrincipalId FROM IsAuthorized ia......
```

Comment: This worked for the most part, did have to put `.ToList()` on the first `list` query... Thanks!

Comment: Great if that helped. Enjoy NHibernate ;)